# How to correctly return an array of ints from service?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, call-service, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following code:

RouteRemainder.srv:

```
---
int64[] route_remainder
```

routes_manager,py:

```
...    
rospy.Service( "/route_remainder", RouteRemainder, self.route_remainder_callback)
...
def route_remainder_callback(self, msg):
    return [1, 2, 3]
```

When I call `rosservice call /route_remainder`, I get:

> ERROR: service [/route_remainder]
> responded with an error: service
> cannot process request: handler
> returned wrong number of values:
> Invalid number of arguments, args
> should be ['route_remainder'] args
> are(1, 2, 3)

What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376899/how-to-correctly-return-an-array-of-ints-from-service?/) by [mbostic](https://answers.ros.org/users/73670/mbostic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to wrap the return value into a tuple:

```
return ([1,2,3],)
```

---

Originally posted by [mbostic](https://answers.ros.org/users/73670/mbostic/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0